# Laravel tags with and query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have an product filter option .and user has product filters of different type in product category page.

**Tags**

```
id | tag_name | slug |
```

**products**

```
id | proudct_name
```

**product_tags**

```
id | product_id | tag_id
```

Now am trying to retrieve all products where tag_name ="ddd" and tag_name="ddd".

It means product should be in both the category .

```
$response=Product::with(['productCategory'])
->when((isset($requestArray)&&count($requestArray)),function ($query)use($requestArray){

            $query->whereHas('productTags', function ($query) use ($requestArray) {

                $query->where(function ($query) use ($requestArray){

                    if (isset($requestArray['filterForm'])&&count($requestArray['filterForm'])){

                        $valueArray=[];
                        foreach ($requestArray['filterForm'] as $key=>$value){


                            if (is_array($value)&&count($value)){


                               $query->whereIn('tags.slug',$value);

                            } elseif($key!="country_list"){

                               $query->where('tags.slug',$value);

                            }


                        }


                    }
                });

            });
        })
            ->whereHas('productCategory',function ($query)use($request,$categoryName){
            $query->where('slug',$categoryName);
        });
```

I have issue when i select combination of mobile brand and mobile color/if i select only one filter group then it works fine

Comment: can u post `$requestArray['filterFrom']`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga.updated

Comment: if you filter the filterForm that you post, it has issue?

Comment: @if my filterform has selection only combination of mobileband and color then it return zero product

Comment: yes, try my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **color** and **mobile_brand** are all in `tags.slug`,

The slug cannot have color's value and mobile_brand's at the same time.

Do something like this:

```php
// You need to build the combination of mobile_band and color to array:
$slugs = array(['green', 'mi'], ['green', 'lg']);

$response = Product::with(['productCategory'])->where(function($query) use ($slugs) {
    forEach ($slugs as $tags)
    {
        $query->orWhere(function($query) use ($tags) {
            forEach($tags as $tag) 
            {
                $query->whereHas('productTags', function($query) use ($tag){
                     $query->where('tags.slug', $tag);
                });
            }
        });        
    }
});
```

Comment: @since you are considering all in wherein .but it should be wherein and where similar like that

Comment: here is the sql query which asked another question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691891/myql-pivot-join-fails/59691916#59691916

Comment: that query works fine but not sure how to convert it to laravel

Comment: @TsaiKoga.sir you are amazing .you have saved me a lots of time.how got that clue for doing combination

Comment: @vision I build those datas and table, and try them locally

Comment: @TsaiKoga.Thank you so much for spending valuable time for me,i learnt new type of query which is not done till now.